# Efficient example implementation of GPU-training of a simple feed-forward NN in TensorFlow? Maybe with tf.data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I just started using the GPU version of TensorFlow hoping that it would speed up the training of my feed-forward neural networks. I am able to train on my GPU (GTX1080ti), but unfortunately it is not notably faster than doing the same training on my CPU (i7-8700K) the current way I’ve implemented it. During training, the GPU appears to barely be utilized at all, which makes me suspect that the bottleneck in my implementation is how the data is copied from the host to the device using feed_dict.

I’ve heard that TensorFlow has something called the “tf.data” pipeline which is supposed to make it easier and faster to feed data to GPUs etc. However I have not been able to find any simple examples where this concept is implemented into multilayer perceptron training as a replacement for feed_dict.

Is anyone aware of such an example and can point me to it? Preferably as simple as possible since I’m new to TensorFlow in general. Or is there something else I should change in my current implementation to make it more efficient? I’m pasting the code I have here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
tf.reset_default_graph()   
import time

# Function for iris dataset.
def get_iris_data():
    iris   = datasets.load_iris()
    data   = iris["data"]
    target = iris["target"]

    # Convert to one-hot vectors
    num_labels = len(np.unique(target))
    all_Y = np.eye(num_labels)[target]
    return train_test_split(data, all_Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=89)
# Function which initializes tensorflow weights & biases for feed-forward NN.
def InitWeights(LayerSizes):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        # Make tf placeholders for network inputs and outputs.
        X = tf.placeholder( shape = (None,LayerSizes[0]),
                            dtype = tf.float32,
                            name ='InputData')
        y = tf.placeholder( shape = (None,LayerSizes[-1]),
                            dtype = tf.float32,
                            name ='OutputData')
        # Initialize weights and biases.
        W = {}; b = {};
        for ii in range(len(LayerSizes)-1):
            layername = f'layer%s' % ii
            with tf.variable_scope(layername):
                ny = LayerSizes[ii]
                nx = LayerSizes[ii+1]
                # Weights (initialized with xavier initializatiion).
                W['Weights_'+layername] = tf.get_variable(
                                    name = 'Weights_'+layername,
                                    shape = (ny, nx),
                                    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                    dtype = tf.float32
                                    )
                # Bias (initialized with xavier initializatiion).
                b['Bias_'+layername] = tf.get_variable(
                                    name = 'Bias_'+layername,
                                    shape = (nx),
                                    initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
                                    dtype = tf.float32
                                    )
    return W, b, X, y
# Function for forward propagation of NN.
def FeedForward(X, W, b):    
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        # Initialize 'a' of first layer to the placeholder of the network input.
        a = X
        # Loop all layers of the network.
        for ii in range(len(W)):
            # Use name of each layer as index.
            layername = f'layer%s' % ii
            ## Weighted sum: z = input*W + b
            z = tf.add(tf.matmul(a, W['Weights_'+layername], name = 'WeightedSum_z_'+layername), b['Bias_'+layername])
            ## Passed through actication fcn: a = h(z)
            if ii == len(W)-1:
                a = z
            else:
                a = tf.nn.relu(z, name = 'activation_a_'+layername)
    return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Import data
    train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = get_iris_data()
    # Define network size [ninputs-by-256-by-outputs]
    LayerSizes = [4, 256, 3]
    # Initialize weights and biases.
    W, b, X, y  = InitWeights(LayerSizes)

    # Define loss function to optimize.
    yhat = FeedForward(X, W, b)
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - yhat),reduction_indices=[0])

    # Define optimizer to use when minimizing loss function.
    all_variables = tf.trainable_variables()
    optimizer     = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.0001)
    train_op      = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list = all_variables)

    # Start tf session and initialize variables.
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Train 10000 minibatches and time how long it takes.   
    t0 = time.time()
    for i in range(10000):
        ObservationsToUse = np.random.choice(len(train_X), 32)
        X_minibatch = train_X[ObservationsToUse,:]
        y_minibatch = train_y[ObservationsToUse,:]
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X : X_minibatch, y : y_minibatch})
    t1 = time.time()

    print('Training took %0.2f seconds' %(t1-t0)) 
    sess.close()
```

Comment: There are actually several official guides about it, like [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), [Data Input Pipeline Performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets) or [Datasets for Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets_for_estimators), in addition to whatever you can find on Google.

Answer (score 0):

The speed might be low because:

- You are creating placeholders. Using numpy, we insert the data in the
  placeholders and thereby they are converted to tensors of the graph.

By using tf.data.Dataset, you can create a direct pipeline which makes the data directly flow into the graph without the need of placeholders. They are fast, scalable and have a number of functions to play around with.

```
    with np.load("/var/data/training_data.npy") as data:
  features = data["features"]
  labels = data["labels"]
    # Assume that each row of `features` corresponds to the same row as `labels`.
    assert features.shape[0] == labels.shape[0]
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
```

Some useful functions :

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32) # Creating batches
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs) # repeat the dataset 'N' times
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() # Create a iterator to retrieve batches of data

X, Y = iterator.get_next()
```

Here, 32 is the **batch size**. 
In your case,

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, targets))
```

Hence, there is no need of placeholders. Directly run,

```
session.run( train_op ) # no feed_dict!!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Forgive my slowness, I’m trying to change my example code to work with some of the tf.data functions you mentioned as a replacement for placeholders but I’m running into some issues. For example, if I don’t create my X and y placeholders, how do I then define the feed forward calculations for my network? In my function “yhat = FeedForward(X,W,b)” the placeholder X is used as input. How would I write the feed forward function without any placeholders?

Comment: Use the batches of data. In the code I provided, 'next_element' is a batch of data, which you can use in your feed forward net.

Comment: Also, I have made some changes in the 2nd code snippet.

Comment: I think I got the feed forward function to work using X from `X, y = iterator.get_next()`. However, when I want to train the network using `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X : X_minibatch, y : y_minibatch})` where `X_minibatch` and `y_minibatch` are generated by `X_minibatch, y_minibatch = iterator.get_next()` Im getting a tensorflow error telling me a tf.Tensor object is not acceptable to feed. Should I not be using feed_dict when giving the minibatch data to the network?

Comment: While using Dataset you will not require any placeholders which need to be fed. There is no need on placeholders and it is not  a hood practice :-)

Comment: So are you saying that the training command simply becomes `sess.run(train_op)` instead of `sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X : X_minibatch, y : y_minibatch})`? If so, then how do I control which data/observations are used during training?

Comment: Yes exactly. Which observations would you like to control?

Comment: Well say my X and y data has 100 000 observations (rows), how would I control which, say 32, of these are fed into the network each time it runs train_top? In my initial example code `X_minibatch` and `y_minibatch` is a subset of the entire dataset. Which observations are in this minibatch is controlled with `ObservationsToUse = np.random.choice(len(train_X), 32)`. But now that I dont feed these variables to the network, how does it know which observations to train on?

Comment: In the code I provided, X and Y are the minibatches themselves.

Comment: Are you saying that as long I write these three commands: `dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_X, train_y));`  `iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() ;` `X, y = iterator.get_next();`, then my dataset will be divided into minibatches? If so, how do I control which observations are in these minibatches and the size of the batches? And say I want to predict a modeled response using an observation from a test dataset with my trained network using the `FeedForward function`, how would I get the iterator to populate X and y with specific observations in a way that I control?